# .htaccess Deny access to image's folder but allow acces to view images

Tags: apache, .htaccess

On one of my websites, a user can access the URL **site.com/galery**. There is no index.html / .php file in this folder so Apache is just listing every single images of the directory galery.

I was wondering, is it possible (using htaccess) to deny direct access to this folder (by typing **site.com/galery**) but still allow a user to see images from this folder with

```
<img src="galery/myPicture.jpg" alt="">
```

EDIT : This topic is not a duplicate. The proposed topic's solutions does not allow to view images as asked in mine.

Thanks !

Comment: The dupe link has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an .htaccess file in this folder with:

```
Options –Indexes
```

Comment: actually you can add this line in the main public html folder .htaccessf file, and all the sub directories that don't have htaccess file ... will be affected too as well.